# Go to the desired location on the page when clicking the navbar in a single-page react-based website

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import "../App.css";
import { GiUbisoftSun } from "react-icons/gi";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
function Header() {
const [header, setHeader] = useState(false);

return (
<div className={header ? "header" : "header active"}>
  <div className="headerContainer">
    <div className="headerWrapper">
      <div className="logo">
        <GiUbisoftSun className="logoIcon" />
        <span className="logoTitle">SQUARESPACE</span>
      </div>
      <Router>
        <div className="links">
          <ul>
            <li className="linkProduct">
              <Link to="#footer">Product</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="linkTemplates">
              <Link to="/Templates">Templates</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="linkResources">
              <Link to="Resources">Resources</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="userEntry">
          <span className="logIn">LOG IN</span>
          <span className="getStarted">GET STARTED</span>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="#footer"></Route>
          <Route path="/users"></Route>
          <Route path="/"></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
}

export default Header;




import React from "react";
import "./footer.css";

function Footer() {
return (
<div className="footer" id="footer">
  <div className="footerContainer">
    <div className="footerWrapper">
      <div className="footerTextIcon">
        © 2023 · Made with  by Barbaros Ihtiyar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
}

export default Footer;
```

I tried something like this but without success. I tried to do it by giving an id, but it shows the id in the link, it does not go to the desired place. When my request is pressed, the page scrolls down to where I want it. I also looked at the react-router-dom documentation, but I couldn't find an answer for myself. In the solutions I tried, I could only change the link on the page, when I clicked it, I couldn't take the page to the desired area. I don't know where I went wrong. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `react-router-dom` itself doesn't really handle hashlinks, if that's what the issue is you are asking about. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do or what any specific issue is that you are asking for help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the react-scroll-to-element library for this.

For example:- https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-to-an-element-on-click-in-reactjs-nku0l?from-embed